# How man base $b$ automorphs are there with n or fewer base $b$ digits if $b$ has prime-power factorization

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Definition: An integer $x \geq 2$ is called an automorph to the base $b$ if the last $n$ base $b$ digits of $x^2$ are the same as those of $x$
>
> Question: How man base $b$ automorphs are there with n or fewer base $b$ digits if $b$ has prime-power factorization?

I solved a similar problem which showed that there are four base 10 automorphs with four digits. These are obtained by solving $x \equiv 1 \text{ or } 0 \mod 2^4 \text{ or } 5^4$.  There were four sets of equations to solve.  I'm wondering how the observation generalizes for the above question.